# Handling of `.hie` files by Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell-stack

I need to generate `*.hie` files for all of my Haskell module files in a project managed by Haskell Stack. I do this, by adding the `-fwrite-ide-info` compilation flag to `stack.yaml` in the following form:

```yaml
ghc-options:
  "$locals": -fwrite-ide-info
```

Let's say the project consists of one package with a library and an executable. A stripped down `package.cabal` would be

```
name: package

library
  exposed-modules:
    Package.Exposed.Module
  ghc-options: -fwrite-ide-info

executable binary
  main-is: Main.hs
    ghc-options: -fwrite-ide-info
    build-depends:
      package
```

Then, I run `stack build`.

During the compilation, the `*.hie` files are generated in the `.stack-work` directory.

To be exact, respectively, the library and executable files are in

```
path/to/project/package/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/Package/...
path/to/project/package/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/binary/binary-tmp/...
```

I need the `*.hie` files in the actual source directories, and, low and behold, those `*.hie` files show up for the library, but not for the executable.

Now my question: How does Haskell Stack handle `*.hie` files. Are they handled in a special way, e.g., are they copied to the source files, where they can be found by programs making use of them (one such program that I want to use is `weeder`)? If not, I have no idea how those `*.hie` files showed up. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that Haskell Stack does not copy/move hie files to the source folders. Maybe it did that at some point, because otherwise I have no idea how the files popped up there. After deletion of the `hie` files in the source folders, `weeder` actually uses the `hie` files in the `.stack-work` directories. I apologize for the confusion.